# NameError: name 'sentiment' is not defined

Tags: python, flask

i am getting this error (NameError: name 'sentiment' is not defined) when i try to get my variable 'sentiment' , even I put it as a global it doesn't work , if anyone can help me please

```
@app.route('/sentiments_analysis', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def sentiments_analysis():
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'largtext' in request:
        global  entities 
        global sentiment
        text = request.form.get['largtext']
        client = language.Client()
        document = client.document_from_text(text)
        sent_analysis = document.analyze_sentiment()
        dir(sent_analysis)
        sent_analysis = document.analyze_entities()
        dir(ent_analysis)
        sentiment = sent_analysis.sentiment
        entities = sent_analysis.entities

    return render_template('sentiments.html',sentiment=sentiment,entities=entities)
```

Comment: you only set sentiment inside your if statement but you return it outside your if statment. So you likely get this error because your if condition wasnt true there for you never set sentiment as a variable yet you try to return it

Answer (score 1):

i solve it by doing this :

```
@app.route('/sentiments_analysis', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def sentiments_analysis():
    entities = ''
    sentiment = ''
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'largtext' in request:
        text = request.form.get['largtext']
        client = language.Client()
        document = client.document_from_text(text)
        sent_analysis = document.analyze_sentiment()
        dir(sent_analysis)
        sent_analysis = document.analyze_entities()
        dir(ent_analysis)
        sentiment = sent_analysis.sentiment
        entities = sent_analysis.entities

    return render_template('sentiments.html',sentiment=sentiment,entities=entities)
```